# Can't modify header information in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have  created a WordPress theme and I have tested it in localhost , it doesn't have any error. But when I uploaded it in the host, in most of pages I see this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/dekadesi/domains/dekadesign.ir/public_html/wp-content/themes/dekadesign_v2/functions.php:1) in /home2/dekadesi/domains/dekadesign.ir/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1179

I checked space in `wp-confing.php` and `functions.php` but my problem is not solved. I need `functions.php` file, I don't know what should I do.

Comment: Use ob_start() function on top of header in php tag

Comment: How do I solve the Headers already sent warning problem?
link: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting

Comment: Please do not put solution material in your questions. If you want to record more details about the answer, please edit your answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your helps ,
I talked to my web hosting manager and they start output_buffering in my host .
then problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

Please add ob_start(); at the top of the functions.php file, issue will be resolved.